# List items in header are not quite centered (using Flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

If viewed on desktop it seems fine, but on mobile there is definitely uneven spacing on the left and right side of the list items.

Note: list items are pink.

Any help in spacing these evenly would be much appreciated!

[image]

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/connorocampo/pen/OoRygB?editors=1100

```
<ul id="flex-nav">  
  <li><a href="#skills" class="nav-link">Skills</a></li>
  <li><a href="#certified" class="nav-link">Certified</a></li>
  <li><a href="#hire" class="nav-link">Hire!</a></li>
</ul>  

<style>
#flex-nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `padding-left: 0` to your container (`#flex-nav`).

List elements come with default padding (or margin).

This is your code in Chrome:

[image]

Also, you can avoid the problem altogether and simplify your code like this:

```css
#flex-nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="flex-nav">  
  <a href="#skills" class="nav-link">Skills</a>
  <a href="#certified" class="nav-link">Certified</a>
  <a href="#hire" class="nav-link">Hire!</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: You are an angel! Thank you for pointing that out! Should have known to use dev tools.

Comment: @connorocampo If this answered worked for you, you should accept it.

Comment: Done! Thank you for pointing that out, too. Still learning the etiquette here.